# How can I fix this homebrew download error?

Tags: download, homebrew

When I download homebrew in terminal (/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)")
I got error like this
How can I download homebrew...?

-functions
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions: Operation not permitted
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
(base) jungsohyun@jeongsohyeon-ui-MacBook-Pro ~ %

-functions
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions: Operation not permitted
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
(base) jungsohyun@jeongsohyeon-ui-MacBook-Pro ~ %